# Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM

Tags: java, windows, installation, installanywhere

I've been trying to install this ARToolkit from Qualcomm: 
https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/
 (Windows ".exe" version) on a Windows 7 64bits platform, and I keep getting the error:

> Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM

The program trying to install this program is InstallAnywhere, but I can't seem to find any documentation about this error. The dialogue box name when the crash happens is 
LaunchAnywhere

I was just wondering if anyone had seen this kind of error before and if so, how to solve it.  The very few answers I can find online relate to Win98/ME issues thus making them irrelevant.

I'm currently using JDK 1.7.0_04 and jre 1.7 if this is somehow relevant.

Comment: We have a similar issue with installers we build ourselves with an old Version (7.1) of InstallAnywhere. It turned out, we did not get the installers to run with a 64bit Java VM. In the end, we bundled a 32bit VM just for the installers to run with. The file, the installer could not find ("windows error 2") was some 32 bit vm dll in "program files (86)". Since you can not change the installer you could try to install a 32bit VM just for the installation time. Once the ARToolkit is installed, I guess you could just switch back (reinstall) to 64 VM and maybe all is still running ;-).

Comment: Note that Windows' message spells "occurred" in the wrong way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Windows error 2' has dozens of meanings (52 that I could find).

The most common one is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, which can be found in `winerror.h`. Without more context, that's the best I can guess. Did you check the event logs to see if there's more information there?

Answer (score 90):

Launch the installer with the following command line parameters:

LAX_VM

For example:
InstallXYZ.exe LAX_VM "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"

Comment: There is a similar issue with Java 8 where the same solution was proposed as a workaround in this article [The Without VM Installer Fails To Launch Using Java 8 Update 60 On Windows](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/ISSUE/The-Without-VM-Installer-Fails-To-Launch-Using-Java-8-Update-60-On-Windows)

Answer (score 33):

In cmd

`C:\Users\Downloads>install.exe LAX_VM "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe"`

Comment: This works perfectly, not sure why it was voted down.

Comment: for uninstalling i edited a .lax file that contained an outdated path to javaw.exe. when installing i used the above, but used javaw.exe, both worked.

Comment: +1 worked perfect for me - But in case of me java.exe was in the default location but exe did not installed?

Comment: @kaiten65 It was voted down because it is a duplicate of the answer posted three months earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander For me, this answer was meaningful. The "duplicated answer" suggests to use Java from the JRE. That didn't work for me, but using it from the JDK as suggested here did work.

Answer (score 13):

For me it works a deleting "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in my system enviroment PATH variable

**Edit:**
If you don't have that variable or it does not work you can directly delete or rename the directory "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath"

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `C:\path\to\java\jre\bin` to your system environment variable PATH and run again. That worked for me!

Comment: You could improve your answer by specifying which specific system environment variable to modify and add more details about what it will do.

Answer (score 2):

We could not uninstall a program, stuck with the "Windows error 2 cannot load Java VM". Added the Java path to the PATH variable, uninstalled and re-installed Java 8, the problem would not go away.

Then I found this solution online and it worked for us on the first shot:
- Uninstall Java 8
- Install Java 6

Whatever the reason, with Java 6, the error went away, we uninstalled the program, and re-installed Java 8.

Comment: +1 from me, that was the only way that helped uninstall Kony Visualiser. How come one cannot uninstall a program without downgrading the version of Java RE is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error after installation:
Find the .lax file with the matching exe name and update current vm path from:

> lax.nl.current.vm=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

to

> lax.nl.current.vm=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe

Comment: Exactly, this cryptic _Windows error 2_ can basically mean you didn't specify a valid Java VM.

Answer (score 1):

I had same mistake, it was produced because i had disabled the creation of "_jvm" in the InstallAnywhere (**project - JVM settings - Installer Settings - Bundled/Downloaded Virtual Machine**), then into file "**Uninstall $PRODUCT_NAME$.lax**" into uninstall folder, the variable "**lax.nl.current.vm**" is empty.

If you don't need jvm is disabled check "**Install Bundled / Downloaded Virtual Machine**" option in the checkbox (project - JVM settings - Installer Settings - Bundled/Downloaded Virtual Machine).

If you need jvm is disabled because you create it manually, then you can do the following:
create an action "**Modify Text File**" to append variable with the value of the _jvm folder.

```
(Existing File)
$USER_INSTALL_DIR$\Uninstall_$PRODUCT_NAME$ \Uninstall $PRODUCT_NAME$.lax

(Append)

lax.nl.current.vm=..\_jvm\bin\java.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `.....\javaw.exe"`. It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after upgrading java from 1.8.0_202 to 1.8.0_211

**Problem:**

Here are directories where new version of 1.8.0_211 of Java installed:

Directory of c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin
Directory of c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

So one is located in 32 bit and second is in 64 bit Program files folder. The one that is specified in the PATH is 32 bit version (c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath), even though it was 64 bit version of the Java that was installed.

**Solution:**

> Change system environments variable PATH from c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath to c:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin